# htaccess regex help

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi
I need some help (the solution and the explanation please)
In my application there is a php page called `page.php` which gets a parameter `page` by `GET` and delivers content accordingly.
What I want is:

1. Make this page the entry point, catch all and redirect it to `page.php`.
2. Use the URI as the `page` parameter value. (`domain.com/string` will become `domain.com/page.php?page=string`)

When I used `^(.*)$ page.php?page=$!` it was working, except it also manipulated every resource that was called (js, css, images, etc..)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `RewriteCond` statements to avoid any existing files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Allow files that exists to bypass rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Almost finished typing exactly the same thing :)  I use exactly this for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @Paul Spencer: It's an extremely common setup these days, most frameworks use something pretty similar. :-)

Comment: 1) thanks, it is the answer. 2) can you tell me what is the regex for such rule? i would like to learn it anyway..

Comment: @yossi: What rule did you want a regex for? Not matching css/jpg/gif/png explicitly?

Comment: Well, seems like i still need some help. it's the correct answer (by it's content) but it's not working when the QueryString is empty.

Comment: @yossi What doesn't work, the rule or does your script not handle `page=`?

Comment: @Orbling, first thanks for the time. as for my problem. I am trying to catch with the rule every request to the server. with the rules above I do, except those without any parameters. (`domain.com/anything` works, while `domain.com` doesn't).  I can use the `page.php` as the index file, but i am trying not to.

Comment: @yossi: I would think that should match that case, add another rule: `RewriteRule ^$ page.php [L,QSA]`